# How to reduce the size of JQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I managed to run the JQuery datepicker into JSF page.

[image]

But as you can see the buttons and the calendar are not symmetric - they are more big than usual. Can you tell me how I can reduce the size of the calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a new css file and place it below the other 'jquery' one, and then add/edit all the necessary ui-datepicker styling (to this new file)  to the one that best fits your needs

Comment: try using inspect element, this way you can identify the classes that you want to modify. See original ones, and then override those values with the new ones. that's all I can tell u